# Python : nested list comprehension

Tags: python

**I have a nested list issue that I cannot solve.**

**Input**

---

```
li=
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9,10,11,12]
```

---

```
newList = [[0 if kk==6 or kk==7 else kk for kk in x] for x in li]
```

### **output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 0, 0, 8]
[9,10,11,12]
```

I want to print this output with list slicing and index

and another **output**

```
[1,2,3,4,8,12,11,10,9,5]
```

like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7CiT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice numpy arrays

```
a=[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 0, 0, 8],
[9,10,11,12]]
b=np.array(a) 
list(b[0:1][0]) + list(b[1:,-1]) + list(b[-1:][0])[-2::-1] + list(b[1:,0])[-2::-1]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 11, 10, 9, 5]
```